# how to save and remember UI state of an activity while application is open

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` in my Activity which has a close button. when I click on the close button the CardView closes, but when I come back to the activity the CardView shows again.
I want that the CardView doesn't show once I close it until I exit or close the application.
[image]

`activity_detail.xml`

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="9dp"
            android:paddingVertical="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_ad_icon"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fa_solid"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:text="@string/fa_bullhorn_ad"
                android:textColor="#636363"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_ads"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:fontFamily="@font/google_sans"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:text="Ads"
                android:textColor="#636363"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_btn_close_ad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fa_solid"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="@string/fa_times_circle_close"
                android:textColor="#79636363"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`DetailActivity.java`

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewBtnCloseAd;
    CardView cardViewAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        // view reference
        textViewBtnCloseAd = findViewById(R.id.textview_btn_close_ad);
        cardViewAd = findViewById(R.id.cardview_ad);


        // close the ad panel
        textViewBtnCloseAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cardViewAd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try save the close state(a boolean value) in a static variable which can be defined in Application or an util class and set your cardViewAd visibility according to the close state get from the static variable when DetailActivity onCreate. The default state could be true. Once reopen the application, the close state reset to true.

Comment: Can you please show me that with some code snippets?